# *nice* in subprocess.call function not working

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> subprocess.call(["echo","Hello there"], env=os.environ)
Hello there
0
>>> subprocess.call(["nice", "19", "echo","Hello there"], env=os.environ)
nice: 19: No such file or directory
127
>>> subprocess.call(["nice", "19", "echo","Hello there"], env=os.environ, shell=True)
0
0
>>>
```

I don't understand why subprocess is not recognizing *nice* there

I have no issues running *nice* in my shell

> $nice -n 19 echo 'hi there'
>
> hi there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot an argument with `"-n"` in your `subprocess.call` call. You probably meant

```
subprocess.call(["nice", "-n", "19", "echo", "Hello there"], env=os.environ)
```